# Скрытие jQuery-скриптов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Веду разработку уникальных скриптов на jQuery и хочу, чтобы их исходный код никто не смог видеть. Могу ли я подключить скрипт таким образом, чтобы он загружался на страницу, но чтобы его исходный код не был виден?

Comment: Его можно захешировать. Был у меня опыт с этим. Есть даже специальные онлайн сервисы для этого. Просто меняете кодировку и в результате получается непонятный для чтения код. Есть еще один способ.Можно загружать скрипты через ajax

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript исполняется на стороне клиента, браузером. На стороне клиента, скрипт должен быть загружен, прочитан и выполнен. Поэтому, Вы никак не сможете полностью защитить свой скрипт.
Для осложнения изучения можно использовать [обфускацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) кода, но это не панацея. Полноценно можно защитить только то, что исполняется на сервере.